# power automate, power bi, python or other automated way to extract full names given azure active directory upn

Tags: python, azure-active-directory, powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I have a dataset exported from jira into csv format containing user aliases which when combined with the known @companydomain.com suffix provide the unique aad [ azure active directory ] upn [ user principal name ] for user associated with each line item.

I'm looking for a d365 power automate or m365 power bi or python or other automated way to read in that csv of upn names and then talk to aad or microsoft graph to extract the associated "full name" for each user and add it as a field to the csv.

Anyone got a solution to that scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you can do it with power automate. But the hardest part with power automate is to parse the csv file, as there is no built in CSV parser, there are 2 or 3 3rd party csv parsing connectors, but you need to sign up to their services to use it. or you could save it as an excel file, because power automate can read excel files.

But if you can get past that part, you don't even have to do a manual graph call for it. Once you get the csv Parsed in power automate, take the information (upn) feed it into the endpoint of Get User profile (V2) put in the upn, and as select fields you can pick like surname or whatever profile parameters are there. then "create csv table" and build a csv that is identical to the csv file plus the new field, then send it as an attachment in an email to yourself. where the content of the attachment is the output of the "create csv table"

Honestly, its kind of long and complicated with power automate personally. If it were me, I'd just write a powershell script to do it.

something like

```
connect-azuread
$csvdata = import-csv -Path "whatever.csv"

foreach ($line in $csvdata){
    $displayname = (get-azureaduser -searchstring "$($line.username)@domain.com").DisplayName
    $line | add-member -notepropertyname FullName -NotePropertyValue $displayname
}
$csvdata | export-csv "whatevermodified.csv"
```

Comment: thanks for the response and the alternative option using powershell that seems like a viable route. i found a python console app example with code to enable doing msal signin and then calls to microsoft graph exposing people and organizational data [ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-daemon/ms-identity-python-webapp/ ].  probably more flexibility manipulating the dataset in python but the ability for the powershell cmdlet enable a signin and aad user object queries without having to get into msal signins and associated app setups feels less complicated.